Laravel routes are not updating on server
When I upload my Laravel application to the server, routes are not being updated. For example, I have added the following simple route, at the very top of the other routes:
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'test';
});

But, when I open test, I get 404, instead of 'test'. Since the app is on the shared hosting, I am unable to run specific commands, however, I did try with
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

on local, and then to re-upload bootstrap and storage folders, however, this did not solve anything.  Of course, everything works on local.
Thanks for any kind of help.

"When I upload my Laravel application to the server" - how exactly do you do that?

I just uploaded all the files using FileZilla... All existing routes are working, but only changes in routes are not being applied.

do you have index.php in root of your application that direct the application to your public folder?

Yes, everything was working properly the first time. However, any changes to the route file are not reflected.

you need to route:clear on server, not on local

I think the url-rewriting is not working. If you host at an apache server, you need to have a working .htaccess file. If you host at an nginx server, you need to have a working web.config file in you public directory.
Als check the root of the public. Sometimes it's public_html or httpdocs.

You can create a route in web.php for clearing all caches
Pattern 01
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $callMsg = '';

    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:10px 0 12px'>Cache cleared ...</h5>";

    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:0 0 12px'>Config cleared ...</h5>";

    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:0 0 12px'>Config Cache cleared ...</h5>";

    Artisan::call('route:cache');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:0 0 12px'>Route Cache cleared ...</h5>";

    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:0 0 12px'>Routes cleared ...</h5>";

    Artisan::call('view:cache');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:0 0 12px'>View Cache cleared ...</h5>";

    Artisan::call('optimize');
    $callMsg .= "<h5 style='margin:0 0 12px'>Site optimized ...</h5>";

    return $callMsg;
});

Pattern 02
Route::get('/clear-cache', function () {
    $cacheCommands = array(
        // 'event:clear',
        'view:clear',
        'cache:clear',
        'route:clear',
        'config:clear',
        'clear-compiled',
        'optimize:clear'
    );

    foreach ($cacheCommands as $command) {
        Artisan::call($command);
    }

   return "Cache cleared successfully";
});

When ever you want to clear the cache on the server side with Laravel Commands, just hit the Url /clear-cache (with your site url) like this

e.g. http(s)://www.foo-boo.com/clear-cache

It is working perfectly for me.
Let me know if it works for you.

Note: At first time, it will give you 404 error, but when you hit the same url second time, it will work perfectly.

Hope it will work for you.

Thanks for the help. I needed to add it first to an existing route, but after that, it worked nicely.

No Problem ... give the answer +1 ;)
