Assets got net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in route `/` on Laravel 10 with Nginx server
I'm getting many net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) errors when trying to access my public/assets file through the route of /, but when I try another route like /home with the same page and same file, it works fine:

I deployed my Laravel 10 project on Ubuntu 22 with Nginx.
This is my Nginx virtual host configuration file:
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/v2-hexagon/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name compro.hexagon.co.id www.compro.hexagon.co.id;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

and this is my routes/web.php file:
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('Home');
})->name('Home');

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('Home');
})->name('Home');

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
})->name('About');

Route::get('/Portofolio', function () {
    return view('Portofolio');
})->name('Portofolio');

Route::get('/Services', function () {
    return view('Services');
})->name('Services');

Route::get('/News', function () {
    return view('News');
})->name('News');

Route::get('/Career', function () {
    return view('Career');
})->name('Career');

Route::get('/Contact', function () {
    return view('Contact');
})->name('Contact');

Route::get('/News/Post/{id}', function ($id) {
    return view('singlepost', ['id' => $id]);
})->name('singlepost');

Route::get('/Portofolio/Post/{id}', function ($id) {
    return view('singleporto', ['id' => $id]);
})->name('singleporto');

// Route::get('/about_layout', function () {
//     return view('about_layout');
// });

Route::get('/Service/IT Consultation', function () {
    return view('IT Consultation');
})->name('IT Consultation');


Route::get('/Service/Digital Marketing', function () {
    return view('Digital Marketing');
})->name('Digital Marketing');


Route::get('/Service/Branding', function () {
    return view('Branding');
})->name('Branding');

I get this kind of error only when accessing the route /. But when I accessing the /home route with same function, it works fine.

You must clear the cache. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78601592/laravel-routes-are-not-updating-on-server/78601913#78601913
hope it will solved your issue :)
